# Use Multiple Condition for counting

Tags: excel

I want to count all data in one field except for two item, CT and X for that one I don't want to count it in.

[image: Case]

but I got issue with the formula, can anybody help.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9,"<>X",A1:A9,"<>CT")
```

[image]